# access parent custom tag attribute result from child custom tag using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

am creating custom tags of the following structure

```
<test test1="" test2="" test3="">
  <result1>result of the test1 condition</result1>
  <result2>result of the test2 condition</result2>
  <result3>result of the test3 condition</result3>
</test>
```

so, i want to access the result of the parent tag  attributes test1, test2, test3 (return value for these attributes is true/false) in the child tags result1, result2, result3 to display the output based on the returned value of the conditions whether it is true or false.

Thanks,
Developer.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while researching a similar problem. For posterity's sake, here is how I've seen this accomplished in the wild. I'll assume that your tags are properly defined in your tag library descriptor file.

**The Parent Tag Class**

```
public class TestTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    // Attributes
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;

    // Setters
    public void setTest1(String str) {
        this.test1 = str;
    }
    // Et Cetera

    // Accessors
    public String getTest1() {
        return this.test1;
    }
    // Et Cetera

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() {
        // Do whatever is necessary here to set values for your attributes
    }

    // Process body
}
```

Since `doStartTag` is invoked before we start processing the body within the tag, we know that we can safely access the attributes that we care about in the child tag.

**Child Tag**

```
public class Result1Tag extends TagSupport {

    // Take care of declaring and setting attributes if necessary

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        //TestTag parent = (TestTag)super.getParent(); Not recommended
        TestTag parent = (TestTag)TagSupport.findAncestorWithClass(this, TestTag.class);

        if (parent == null) {
            throw new JspTagException("Result1Tag must be enclosed in a TestTag");
        }

        String test1 = parent.getTest1();

        // Whatever logic you need for this attribute to generate content
    }
}
```

The reason that the use of `getParent()` is discouraged here is that it retrieves only the closest enclosing tag. This limits us if we need to refactor our code.

```
<test test1="foo" test2="bar" test3="foobar">
    <c:if test="${ condition }">
        <result1/>
    </c:if>
    <result2/>
    <result3/>
</test>
```

- With the getParent() implementation, we fail to retrieve the parent tag because the JSTL tag that we inserted is now the closest enclosing tag.
- With findAncestorWithClass() implementation, we successfully retrieve the parent tag because we iteratively search for an ancestor tag with the specified class.

Comment: your ans help me a lot..thank you so much for that...here is additional query that how can we access child data in parent ?